# Proof of a Epigraph that is not convex

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, convex-analysis

> Let the $g: [-2, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
>   $g(x) = \begin{cases} 2x^2 \quad \text{  if } -2 \leq x \leq 0 \\
>  x+2 \quad \text{if } 0 < x \leq 2 \end{cases}$
>
> Prove by definition: "Epi $g$ is not convex"

I'm not sure how you prove the above. I tried by stating "Epi $g$ is not convex $\iff g$ is not convex''. I defined $g_1 \in g: [-2,0] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g_1(x) = 2x^2$ and $g_2 \in g : (0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g_2(x) = x + 2$.

I know that $\lim_{x \uparrow 0} g_1(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} g_2(x)= 2$. At point $x = 0$ we see that the $g(x)$ is not continuous. Applying the definition ''$g$ is convex $\implies g$ is continuous" yields that $g(x)$ is not convex, hence Epi $g$ is not convex.

What do you think? Is this an appropriate proof?
I think it isn't. I think you have to prove it by contradiction. That you should prove the convexity of $g$ with the definition "for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $g(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y) \leq \lambda g(x) + (1 - \lambda) g(y)$" and that you will end with something like $2 \leq 0$ which isn't true and therefore not convex etc. But how do you construct such a proof with a splitted function like $g(x) = \begin{cases} 2x^2 \quad \text{  if } -2 \leq x \leq 0 \\
 x+2 \quad \text{if } 0 < x \leq 2 \end{cases}$ ?

Comment: Let's back up for a second.  Forgetting about a formal proof, do you believe that the epigraph is not convex?  I'm guessing you do, to the point that you'd bet a lot of money on it.  Can you explain why you believe that?  Informally is fine.

Comment: @littleO Yes, I believe that because there is a property "$f$ is convex $\iff$ Epi $f$ is convex". So I assumed that if $g$ is not convex, then it must be that Epi $g$ is also not convex. Therefore I want to prove that $g$ is not convex.

Comment: The first proof you gave is actually ok, since you already know the theorem about convexity implying continuity.  But, in my opinion, it would be much simpler and more direct to just visualize the epigraph of $g$ and show directly that the epigraph is not a convex set.  You see it immediately when you draw the picture.  And this could be made into a careful proof without much trouble.  Invoking the "convexity implies continuity" theorem is sort of like using a cannon to kill a mosquito.

Answer (score 2):

$$ {\rm epi}\ g=\{ (x,y)|g(x)\leq y \} $$

Note that $(0,0),\ (2,4)\in {\rm epi}\ g$ Hence if ${\rm epi}\ g$ is
convex then $$ \frac{1}{2} \{ (0,0)+(2,4)\}=(1,2)\in {\rm epi}\ g$$

But $$ g(1)=3\Rightarrow (1,t)\in {\rm epi}\ g,\ t\geq 3$$

It is a contradiction.

Comment: And while this proof does not require drawing a picture, I'm sure you first drew a picture of the epigraph of $g$ and noticed that the line connecting $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$ goes out of bounds.